# How can i prove this inequality $\prod_{i=2}^n \log{i} \geq 3^{n+1} $?

Tags: inequality, products

How can I prove this?
*(This should be shown starting from $n_0 \geq 0$ s.t it's will be true for any $n \geq n_0 $, and need to find $K>0$ [while K is constant])*

$$K*\prod_{i=2}^n \log{i} \geq 3^{n+1} $$

I don't have any idea, how to simplify this product..

the base of $log$ is 2.

Comment: i would say induction

Comment: $\log_2 2 \ge 3^3$...?

Comment: @NickLiu , read again the question - *This should be shown starting from $n_0$* , "for example: for $ n \geq 3 $ , or for $ n \geq 25 $ ..."

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: There is no need for induction. A direct argument shows that the inequality is valid for all $n$ bigger than a certain threshhold (that depends on $K$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n\geq 2^{2^3}=512$, we have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\sum_{k=2}^{n} \log(\log(k)) &=& 
\sum_{k=2}^{511} \log(\log(k))+\sum_{k=512}^{n} \log(\log(k)) \\
&\geq& \sum_{k=2}^{511} \log(\log(2)) +\sum_{k=512}^{n} \log(\log(512)) \\
&=&\sum_{k=2}^{511} 0+\sum_{k=512}^{n} 2\log(3) \\
&=& (n-511)(2\log(3)) \\
&=& (n+1+n-1023)\log(3) \\
\end{array}
$$

We deduce that for $n\geq 1023$, we have $\sum_{k=2}^{n} \log(\log(k))  \geq (n+1)\log(3)$. QED

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward induction: verify the inequality for $n$ for the smallest valid base case and then complete the induction for $n\geq7$. From the induction hypothesis, multiply both sides with $log_2 (n+1)$ and then use the fact that $log_2 (n+1) \geq 3$